# Dynamically set form name in ng-messages

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-messages

Within multiple forms in my app, I am trying to use the same directive which is an email input field complete with validation (it sources its value from a list of recently used emails but that is not pertinent to this question). Because the form in which the directive is used is different depending on where I use it, the ng-messages attribute needs to be dynamically rendered.

I have managed to get ng-messages to dynamically set itself, but it is not working as expected. Here is the code:

form.html

```
<form name="joinForm">
    <rt-recents-menu ng-model="vm.roomName"/>
</form>
```

directive.coffee

```
recents = angular.module 'rtRecents', ['ionic', 'ngMessages']
  .factory('rtRecentsService', require './recentsService')
  .directive('rtRecentsMenu', (rtRecentsService, $ionicActionSheet) ->
    restrict: 'E'
    template: require './recentsMenu.html'
    scope:
      ngModel: '=?'
    require: ['?ngModel', '^form']
    transclude: false
    replace: false
    link: (scope, element, attrs, ctrls) ->
      ngModel = ctrls[0]
      formCtrl = ctrls[1]
      scope.formName = formCtrl.$name

module.exports = recents.name
```

directive.html

```
<div class="email-line">
      <input type="email"
        name="roomName"
        required
        ng-model="ngModel"
        ng-keydown="onKeyDown()"/>
      <div id="email-error-messages" ng-messages="{{formName}}.roomName.$error" multiple role="alert">
        <div ng-message="required" class="warn" translate>VALIDATION.EMAIL_REQUIRED_ERROR</div>
        <div ng-message="email" class="warn" translate>VALIDATION.EMAIL_INVALID_ERROR</div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This was a pain. googling for this problem only gives people using a single form on a page with a lot of ng-repeat generated input fields. Took a while to figure out. Let me know how the below works for you, if you need to adjust it a little I may can help. Happy ngCoding!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I have a  that displays each of the returned rows from a db query. And each row had its own form within this repeat loop.

I ran into two problems:

1. The ngMessage errors didn't display correctly because they didn't seem to be tied to the right fields/form.
2. I couldn't disable the "save" button per-form. The $invalid didn't seem to work.

Here's what works (trimmed decorators, etc so you only see the essential points):

```
<div ng-repeat="row in rows | orderBy: 'sortBy'"
    ng-init="formName = 'siteEdit' + row.id">
    <form name="{{formName}}" ng-submit="view.startSave(row.id)">
        <!-- I have "control" buttons at the top of my form to save, cancel, etc. here are the two related to saving -->
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save pull-right q-palette-color-2" ng-disabled="view.isPageBusy()"
            ng-show="! this[formName].$invalid" ng-click="view.startSave(row.id)" title="Save"/>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle pull-right q-palette-accent-2"
            ng-show="this[formName].$invalid" style="padding-left:10px;cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Correct Errors To Save"/>
        <label for="siteName{{row.id}}">&nbsp;&nbsp;Name:</label>
            <input id="siteName{{row.id}}"
                class="form-control input"
                type="text"
                placeholder="name"
                ng-disabled="view.isPageBusy()"
                ng-model="row.name"
                name="name"
                required />
            <div ng-messages="formName.name.$error">
                <div ng-message="required">This field is required</div>
            </div>
        .....
    </form>
</div>
```

Key points:

- ng-init in the ng-repeat builds the formName variable.
- form validation for save/etc uses this[formName].$invalid
- Field validation is referenced in the format of formName..$error

Something to note:

I couldn't get the ng-disable to actually disable the "button" based on it being invalid or not (the ng-click executed no matter what, maybe because I didn't use `<button>` but used `<span>` w/ `glyphicon`). So I opted to have one displayed when you can save, the other displayed when you can't. Works better this way since the person can visually see they can't save, and if they hover over they'll see they need to correct the form first.